# Por qué no funciona la barra de menú en el primer click?

Tags: jquery

Hola amigos les comparto el enlace de mi página web la cual está en desarrollo y modificaciones. Lo que sucede es que cuando esta en dispositivo móvil le tengo un menú hamburguesa. sin embargo con el primer click no aparece el submenú.

[chavilla.netlify.com](https://chavilla.netlify.com/)

Mi código jquery es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($(window).width() <=768){

        var contador=1;

        $('#icono-menu').on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            if (contador==1)
            {
                $('#menu').css({
                    'left':'-100%'
                });

                contador=0;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#menu').css({
                    'left':'0'
                }); 

                contador=1;
            }


        });

    }
});
```

Prueben ustedes mismos en la página y se darán cuenta de que les hablo

Comment: Buenas, inicializas el `var contador=1` y cuando haces click compruebas si `comtador==1` entonces lo ocultas. Por lo que la primera acción es ocultarlo, pero ya está oculto por defecto. Tendrías que inicializarlo por ejemplo a `0`

Comment: matahombres así mismo era. Muchas gracias bro